# Convergence of infinite products

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, reference-request, cesaro-summable

I wonder, parallel to the theory of summability of infinite series is there a theory for infinite products?

Is there any generalized convergence method (such as Cesaro and Abel summability) for the convergence of infinite products?

Comment: The convergence of infinite products can be reduced to convergence of infinite sums by taking log.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria

Comment: Since you have used the tag 'reference-request', I would like to mention that the book on Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi has a very elegant and beautiful discussion of infinite products in context of complex analysis.

Comment: A quick google search for the phrase "infinite products" along with the word "summability" turned up a lot of hits, including [this 1929 paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2370588).

Comment: On more reference is vol3. ch. 11, $\S$36 of a fundamental book “Differential and Integral Calculus” by [Grigorii Fichtenholz. This is a famous book for our students and it has many translations (but except English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorii_Fichtenholz).

Answer (score 0):

The test for convergence for infinite multiplication is simple. If you are taking a product from 0 to infinity of a(n), then it converges to a nonzero real number if the infinite *sum* from 0 to infinity of log(a(n) is convergent.